# Relevance of conductors being equipotential in the proof of second uniqueness theorem

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage, conductors

I am going over the proof of second uniqueness theorem in International 4th Ed of Griffiths Electricity and Magnetism. In page 122, followed till the part where two fields $\vec{E_1}$ and $\vec{E_2}$ were taken such that the satisfy gauss's law on each conductor inside the volume of consideration, and then, $\vec{E_3}$, the difference, being taken such that it obeys the following results:

$$ \vec{E_3} = \vec{E}_1 - \vec{E}_2 \tag{1}$$
In region between conductors:
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{E_3} = 0 \tag{2}$$
Over each boundary surface:
$$ \oint \vec{E_3} \cdot da = 0 \tag{3}$$

Now, after this Griffith mentions that there is one final piece of information to complete the proof

> Although we do not know how the charge $Q_i$ distributes itself over the ith conductor, we do know that each conductor is an equipotential, and hence $V_3$ is a constant (not necessarily the same constant) over each conducting surface. (It need not be zero, for the potentials $V_1$ and $V_2$ may not be equal - all we know for sure is that both are constant over any given conductor.)

I went over this paragraph a few times but I still can't understand what role it played in the proof.. because it seems to me that the rest can be done without it even being considered. Here is how I think it would play out:

$$ \int_V \nabla \cdot (V_3 \vec{E}_3) d \tau = \int_V \underbrace{ V_3 ( \nabla \cdot \vec{E}_3) }+ \vec{E}_3 \cdot (\nabla V_3) dV=- \int_V (\vec{E_3})^2 dV$$

Underbraced term zero due to (2), and by the divergence theorem, the LHS becomes:

$$ \int_V V_3 \vec{E_3} \cdot dA = -\int_V (\vec{E_3})^2 dV$$

Now conside a sufficiently large surface containing our charge distribution such that $V=0$ at all points on boundary of this surface (potential at infinity is zero), then it must be that:

$$ \int_V \vec{E_3} \cdot \vec{E_3} dV=0$$

The only way the above equality can happen is if $\vec{E_3} = 0$  through all of spaces since the integrand is a strictly positive quantity.

Hence my question, what is the point of the quoted paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume $V$ consists of the free space between the outer boundary and the conductors;  it does not include the conductors themselves.  This means that the boundary of $V$ is not just the outer boundary, but also includes the surfaces of the conductors.  Even if you define your potential such that $V_3 = 0$ on the outer boundary (we can always do this by adding or subtracting a constant), this does not immediately imply that $V_3 = 0$ on the other pieces of the boundary, namely the surfaces of the conductors.  In fact, that's what you're trying to prove.

The fact that $V_3$ must be constant over the surface of each conductor comes into play because it implies that for the surface $S_i$ of each individual conductor, we have
$$
\int_{S_i} V_3 \vec{E}_3 \cdot d\vec{a} = V_3 \int_{S_i} \vec{E}_3 \cdot d\vec{a},
$$
and each of these latter integrals vanishes by your Eq. (3).  Without the constancy of $V_3$, we cannot argue that these surface integrals all vanish.  From there, the proof proceeds as you have it.

Of course, you could redefine your volume $V$ so that it consists of everything inside the outer boundary, including the conductors.  But in that case, you have charge inside $V$, so Laplace's equation doesn't hold in the first place and the whole proof falls apart.

Comment: ". This means that the boundary of V is not just the outer boundary, but also includes the surfaces of the conductors" I am really confused here, so to understand, I thought of the 'cheese' with holes. Are you saying that the surface of the holes in the cheese is also boundary of the cheese? [picture](https://www.google.com/search?q=cheese+with+holes&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02_wSZX0k1dQi5mU3FFi_dSQtqufw:1622041428704&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8oqyZz-fwAhVMhf0HHcEeAD4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1710&bih=967)

Comment: In the last sentece "you have charge inside V, so Poisson's equation doesn't hold in the first place and the whole proof falls apart." I don't think I have used poissons equation in writing any of my statements

Comment: @Buraian:  Yes, that's correct.  For a simpler example, if $V$ was a thick spherical shell $a< r < b$, then the boundary of $V$ would consists of the two spheres $r = a$ and $r = b$.

Comment: @Buraian:  Sorry, I meant Laplace's equation, which is equivalent to saying that $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}_3 = 0$.

Comment: Ohhh I see. I think the answer is brilliant but I think I'll take a bit of time digest the boundary thing. Thank you @Micheal Seifert ^^

Comment: Hi micheal, after thinking a bit mroe about your answer, it led me to this [other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/639216/on-the-electric-field-taken-in-the-proof-of-the-second-uniqueness-theorem) it'd be nice if you could have a look in it as well.

Comment: Michael, I went through your proof again and I am again stuck at this last statement "But in that case, you have charge inside V, so Laplace's equation doesn't hold in the first place and the whole proof falls apart.". Here, even if you have charge or not, since this new auxillary vector field would be zero anyways since it's the difference, right? So I don't get how there is an issue with laplace's equation

Comment: @Buraian:  We know that $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}_3 = 0$ in the space between the outer surface and the conductors, since we are assuming that $\rho$ is specified there and $\vec{E}_3$ is the difference there.  But we don't know for sure that $\rho = 0$ everywhere for $\vec{E}_3$ on the surface of the conductors;  while we know that the net charges on the conductors are the same in configurations #1 and #2, they could be distributed differently.  So if we included the conductors in $V$, we would not necessarily have $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}_3 = 0$ in $V$.

Comment: Ohh thank you, that was very carefully thought out. I'll think  I'll ponder on what you said a bit more