# On the electric field taken in the proof of the second uniqueness theorem

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

In the proof of uniqueness theorem, we consider $$\vec{E}_3 = \vec{E}_2 - \vec{E_1}$$ where $\vec{E_2}$ and $\vec{E_1}$ are electric fields which satisfy all the boundary condition required.

Now, it maybe noted that due to both $\vec{E}_1$ and $\vec{E}_2$ satisfying all the conditions that the difference $\vec{E}_3$ doesn't really satisfy any of the conditions.

Since $\nabla \cdot \vec{E}_3 = 0$ everywhere and $\oint \vec{E_3} \cdot dA= 0$ over every boundary surface.

This leads me to wonder, is the $\vec{E}_3$ we define meant to be a physical field or just an 'auxiliary' mathematical function used in proof? I ask this because from my understanding if an electric field is physical then it must equal the charge density by $\epsilon_o$ wherever there is charge.

[Previous question for more context](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639139/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more or less just a mathematical construct.  If you want to solve the problem of the electric field created by a charge density $\rho$, then you have $\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = \rho$.  If we assume that both $\vec{E}_1$ and $\vec{E}_2$ satisfy this equation, then their difference satisfies
$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot (\vec{E}_2 - \vec{E}_1) = \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}_2 - \vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{E}_1 = \rho - \rho = 0.
$$
So it wouldn't be a solution to the "real problem" you're trying to solve.

You could, however, interpret it to be a solution to a different problem, one in which there are no charges present ($\rho = 0$) in the volume of interest.  In other words, it's not entirely unphysical, it's just the solution to a different physical situation than the original one.

Comment: Thank you for the help!